# What does "cannelloni" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "cannelloni" mean?
"Canne" means reeds, I think. It seems to be a compound of two words or an adjective added to the word.

Comment: But in Italy "cannellino" is meaning some different things: a type of beans white and creamy, largely used in Tuscany, and a white wine with very fresh and good taste produced near Rome (e.g. "Cannellino di Frascati").

Answer (score 6):

The word itself denote a type of [pasta](https://www.google.com/search?q=cannellone&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6waXK1pnlAhXD0KQKHcWzC5MQ_AUIEigB&biw=1598&bih=774) (as per the previous answer).

It is not a compound word, but a word "mutated" with the suffix **"-one"** which in Italian is referred as *"accrescitivo"* (augmentative). I take here the [definition from Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/accrescitivo/)

> 2. s. m. a. In grammatica, derivazione morfologica di un nome (sostantivo o, meno spesso, aggettivo), per indicarne un accrescimento quantitativo o qualitativo. Si forma di regola con il suffisso -óne (f. -óna)
>
> On grammar, morphological derivation of a noun (or less frequently, an adjective) to denote an augmentation, on quantity or quality. Usually formed with the suffix  *-óne* (feminine: *-óna*)

For example: ragazzo -> ragazzone (boy -> big boy).

As "[cannello](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cannello/)" in Italian can indicate something cylindrical - in fact, it derives from *[canna](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/canna/)* which can have the same generic meaning:

> 3. Tubo o canale di varia grandezza e di qualunque materia:
>
> Tube or pipe with various sizes and of any material

the name of this pasta literally means "big tube" or "big pipe" because of its shape.

Other suffixes with different purposes are:

**diminutive (diminutive):**
-ino, -etto (feminine: -ina, -etta)

e.g. ragazzino, ragazzetto -> little boy

**vezzeggiativo (term of endearment)**
-ello, -etto, -uccio (feminine: -ella, -etta, -uccia)

e.g. cavalluccio -> cute pony

**peggiorativo**
-accio (feminine: -accia)

e.g. ragazzaccio -> nasty boy

Comment: You might want to mention that _cannello_ itself is derived from _canna_.

Comment: @Dag answer edited